# Is javascript the only way for DOM and flash plugins to "talk"?

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, web

I've often seen that whenever flash plugins need to transfer data to the page (which is outside the flash plugin), javascript would be used as the intermediary.

I was wondering are there other solutions? i.e. is it possible for the page to "talk" to the plugin and viceversa while javascript is disabled on the client side ?

Comment: FlashVars allow the server/HTML to pass variables to Flash. Flash itself can also GET/POST, etc.

Comment: If javascript is disabled, what is going to do the talking?

Comment: @Eric I don't understand your question. some other technology of course, which isn't javascript.

Comment: @Pacerier: _"is it possible for the page to "talk" to the plugin"_ - "The page" is just an HTML document. That's like asking a text document to "talk" to your C++ application.

Comment: @Eric pardon the phrasing then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If javascript is disabled there could be communication between Flash and PHP. If there is no Javascript turned on there couldn't be real-time communication between the Flash and the page. For example: If you have a video site the client would request certain video. This means that javascript should determine which video is requested and then the server should deliver it. So in my opinion Javascript is very necessary in many cases concerning Flash plugins. I know many video sites excluding youtube where you can't watch a video without Javascript turned on.

Comment: Just to confirm, communication is only from Flash **to** PHP, and not the other way round right?

Answer (score 0):

yes, Javascript is the only way out here.

Comment: In most cases. But try to watch youtube videos without javascript, they still work.

Comment: @George this is weird. Shouldn't it either be "yes, javascript is the only way" or "no, there are some other technologies capable of doing it" ?

Comment: As I know Youtube is written mainly in Python and after experimenting I found out that turning off javascript doesn't block video watching. So javascript is not the only one technology for communication between flash application and server.